# Why is my cascade not working? - Integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys, symfony

I have an parent and child entities, parent being an image, and child being a vote for the image

```
class Image {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, name="file_name")
     * @var string $fileName
     */
    protected $fileName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, name="title", nullable=true)
     * @var string $title
     */
    protected $title = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, name="author", nullable=true)
     * @var string $author
     */
    protected $author = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="upload_at")
     */
    protected $uploadDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", name="in_pool")
     */
    protected $inPool;

    /**
    * One image has many votes
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Vote", mappedBy="image")
    */
    private $votes;
```

Child:

```
class Vote
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Image", inversedBy="votes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $image;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="date")
     */
    protected $date;

    /**
     * This is internal variable, it does not have to be mapped into database field
     * @var int Counter of votes for an Image
     */
    private $counter;
```

As you can see I have the `@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")` set in the entity.

However when I try to remove an image which has votes I get this:

> An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM image WHERE id = ?'
>   with params [24]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`konkurs`.`vote`,
>   CONSTRAINT `FK_5A1085643DA5256D` FOREIGN KEY (`image_id`) REFERENCES
>   `image` (`id`))

The code used to delete an image based on id looks like this:

```
/**
* @Route("/admin/removeimage/{id}", name="admin-remove-image")
*/
public function adminRemoveImage($id)
{

    $em = $this->getEm();
    $image = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Image')->findOneById($id);
    $fileName = $image->getFileName();

    $em->remove($image);
    $em->flush();

    unlink('uploads/'.$fileName);
    unlink('media/cache/my_thumb/uploads/'.$fileName);

    return $this->redirectToRoute('admin-panel');
}
```

---

Could anyone tell me why does this relation keep failing?

**UPDATE**
Here is the output of using `SHOW CREATE TABLE vote`

> | vote  | CREATE TABLE `vote` (   `id` int(11) NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT,   `date` datetime NOT NULL,   `image_id` int(11)
>   DEFAULT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),   KEY `IDX_5A1085643DA5256D`
>   (`image_id`),   CONSTRAINT `FK_5A1085643DA5256D` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`image_id`) REFERENCES `image` (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB
>   AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |

Comment: What's the output of sql: `SHOW CREATE TABLE vote` or console: `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`?

Comment: Take a look at how to define cascade operations with Doctrine: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations

Comment: @fyrye Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")` is a mapping for the tables that doctrine manages via `doctrine:schema:update` or `doctrine:schema:create`.

The cascade foreign key reference is not automatically applied to the database table column, unless the above commands are issued.

By default, when creating a foreign key reference, it is set to `ON DELETE RESTRICT`.

To resolve your issue run the following SQL commands:

```
ALTER TABLE `vote` DROP FOREIGN KEY `FK_5A1085643DA5256D`;

ALTER TABLE `vote` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_5A1085643DA5256D` FOREIGN KEY (`image_id`) REFERENCES `image` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Which will be the same as running:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

However the schema update may cause irreversible changes/damage to your database structure.

See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#creating-the-database-tables-schema

I also suggest running `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` to determine other potential misconfigurations from editing the doctrine entity mappings.

---

Alternatively as @Cerad mentioned, you can tell Doctrine to manage the relationships, without relying on foreign key references, by using `cascade={"remove"}` like so.

```
class Image 
{
    //...

    /**
    * One image has many votes
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Vote", mappedBy="image", cascade={"remove"})
    */
    private $votes;
}
```

This will tell symfony to issue a delete statement for the `Vote` entity collection associated with the `Image` entity when the `Image` entity is removed.

One caveat is that this only works when issuing commands against the Entity manager, and not the DBAL query builder.

Reference: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#removing-entities

Comment: Both `--dump-sql` and `--force` result in the same response: **Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.**

Comment: Be sure you run `php bin/console cache:clear` prior to the schema, so that the configuration is regenerated. The SQL statement will resolve the issue regardless. Be warned running `--force` can cause loss of data. You may also need to run `php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`

Comment: Same result. Adding the ` cascade={"remove"}` into the image solved the problem. Thank you

Comment: Be sure to fix your vote foreign key reference with the `ALTER TABLE` sql query, otherwise you may run into issues.